# Python 3: Storing a range in a list to be used in a function?

Tags: python, list, function, python-3.x, range

I need to create a list of every number until a very large specific number. This list of numbers then needs to go through a function I created that will spit back out every number that returns True. From all these True numbers, I need to grab the 300th one and print it.

```
def p(n):
  return n==n[::-1]
def s(n):
  return list(filter(p ,n))
```

This is the function that the list will go through.  Tips?

Comment: The vagueness of the phrasing is confusing. Is there an actual use case, or is this a homework assignment?

Comment: Also, could you maybe provide example input/output/intermediate steps?

Comment: what's the actual problem here?

Answer (score 2):

If I'm understanding correctly, you could build it with generators and `islice`

```
from itertools import islice

nums = map(str, range(11, 300))
palindromes = (num for num in nums if num == num[::-1])
ix = islice(palindromes, 15, None)
print(next(ix))
```

Comment: This is an awesome solution.  Could you use a generator instead of `map` so that it's iterables all the way through?

Comment: @SamMussmann The OP was flagged Py3, so `map` is assumed to be a generator. Otherwise, you can replace `range` with `xrange` and `map` with `imap` (But yeah, I guess one could write `nums = (str(n) for n in range(300))` or something)

Comment: Ah -- I am living in a 2.x world and was unaware that these return iterables in Py3.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> list(range(10))
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Note that this all sounds very slow, and you can probably optimize a lot. For example your palindrome check (`p(n)`) could be changed to compare only the first half of the list with the reversed last half. Or actually iterate through the elements simultaneously from the beginning and the top and return false as soon as it fails:

```
def checkPalindrome (seq):
    for i in range(len(seq)):
        if seq[i] != seq[-i-1]:
            return False
    return True
```